# How to Correct wrong Environment setup?

Tags: ros, environment, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to set up my environment variables and typed in the following code:

```
echo "source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Later i realised i only had groovy, so i changed electric in above to groovy but whenever i try to run ros or baxter, always this message gets displayed that

```
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

My question is how to get the wrong environment set-up command disabled so that the irritating message is not displayed again and again? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193826/how-to-correct-wrong-environment-setup?/) by [GoBaxter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20265/gobaxter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just remove all lines with `electric` from your `~/.bashrc` with a text editor.

The second message seems to indicate that not `roscore` is running.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GoBaxter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20265/gobaxter/) on 2014-09-30**:
Where is `~/.bashrc`  located?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-09-30**:
in your home directory

**Comment by [GoBaxter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20265/gobaxter/) on 2014-09-30**:
Thanks. That solved my problem.